# Jquery ScrollTop not working with fixed element

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, scrollmagic

I have created a div fixed to the bottom of screen.  On click I want it to scroll to the next class.  I can get the .top value but it doesn't scroll.  I have jQuery installed and have spent 3 hours trying everything on here.  The project uses magic scroll but no idea how to use that - I am adding to an existing project.  Could this be preventing it from working? I would just use anchor tags but the button needs to be on the screen at all times when the user scrolls (so one button does all).  I have tried this: [scroll up/down to sections with fixed buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444717/scroll-up-down-to-sections-with-fixed-buttons) - same result no scrolling occurs

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("click", ".next", function(e) {

    topPos = $(".container").eq($(".container").index($('.container')) + 1); //find next container
    console.log("Top" + topPos.position().top); //this outputs 1536.09375 for the second container
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: topPos
    }, 1000);
  });

});
```

```css
  .next {
  bottom: 15px;
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 22px 23px 26px 23px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 19%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.down-arrow {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 21px;
  width: 21px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: border-width 150ms ease-in-out;
  &:hover {
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    border-right-width: 4px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="next">
  <div class="down-arrow"></div>
</div>
<article>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at nibh malesuada, imperdiet purus et, laoreet diam. Vivamus ullamcorper gravida magna, vitae rutrum nibh viverra id. Duis eu nibh dolor. Pellentesque congue a dui in volutpat. Ut non placerat
      massa. Donec sollicitudin risus hendrerit tortor dignissim pharetra. Nam eu erat vel nulla elementum dictum consequat ut mauris. Donec egestas in nunc ut convallis. Fusce elit nisl, pulvinar et varius sed, sodales non elit. Duis a augue non quam
      maximus volutpat. Proin rhoncus lacus tempor, laoreet massa nec, venenatis tellus. Suspendisse eros sem, convallis vel risus ac, ultrices mattis justo. Morbi sit amet lectus vestibulum, lobortis tortor sed, tempor mi. Aliquam pretium, risus egestas
      sodales lobortis, sem sem vulputate elit, in lacinia neque tellus non elit.</p>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at nibh malesuada, imperdiet purus et, laoreet diam. Vivamus ullamcorper gravida magna, vitae rutrum nibh viverra id. Duis eu nibh dolor. Pellentesque congue a dui in volutpat. Ut non placerat
      massa. Donec sollicitudin risus hendrerit tortor dignissim pharetra. Nam eu erat vel nulla elementum dictum consequat ut mauris. Donec egestas in nunc ut convallis. Fusce elit nisl, pulvinar et varius sed, sodales non elit. Duis a augue non quam
      maximus volutpat.</p>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at nibh malesuada, imperdiet purus et, laoreet diam. Vivamus ullamcorper gravida magna, vitae rutrum nibh viverra id. Duis eu nibh dolor. Pellentesque congue a dui in volutpat. Ut non placerat
      massa. Donec sollicitudin risus hendrerit tortor dignissim pharetra. Nam eu erat vel nulla elementum dictum consequat ut mauris. Donec egestas in nunc ut convallis. Fusce elit nisl, pulvinar et varius sed, sodales non elit. Duis a augue non quam
      maximus volutpat. Proin rhoncus lacus tempor, laoreet massa nec, venenatis tellus. Suspendisse eros sem, convallis vel risus ac, ultrices mattis justo. Morbi sit amet lectus vestibulum, lobortis tortor sed, tempor mi. Aliquam pretium, risus egestas
      sodales lobortis, sem sem vulputate elit, in lacinia neque tellus non elit.Fusce elit nisl, pulvinar et varius sed, sodales non elit. Duis a augue non quam maximus volutpat. Proin rhoncus lacus tempor, laoreet massa nec, venenatis tellus. Suspendisse
      eros sem, convallis vel risus ac, ultrices mattis justo. Morbi sit amet lectus vestibulum, lobortis tortor sed, tempor mi. Aliquam pretium, risus egestas sodales lobortis, sem sem vulputate elit, in lacinia neque tellus non elit.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var containerIndex = 0;
        $(document).on("click", ".next", function(e) {
            if(!$(".container:eq("+containerIndex+")").length) { return false; }
            topPos = $(".container:eq("+containerIndex+")").offset().top;
            containerIndex++;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: topPos
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Hermal, It returns false so no scroll happens?

Comment: Yes, when no more ".container" available for scrolling and it's working ?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the amount the user has scrolled and look for elements past that point to know which one is next.  Then just grab the first one and scroll to it.

As a side note, since you're doing a delegate event listener, you technically don't need a document ready.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".next", function(e) {
  const scrolledDistance = window.pageYOffset;
  const $containersLaterOnThePage = $('.container').filter(function() {
    return this.offsetTop > scrolledDistance;
  });

  if ($containersLaterOnThePage.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $containersLaterOnThePage.get(0).offsetTop
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
.next {
  bottom: 15px;
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 22px 23px 26px 23px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 19%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.down-arrow {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 21px;
  width: 21px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: border-width 150ms ease-in-out;
  &:hover {
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    border-right-width: 4px;
  }
}

body { min-height: 1000px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="next">
  <div class="down-arrow"></div>
</div>
<article>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at nibh malesuada, imperdiet purus et, laoreet diam. Vivamus ullamcorper gravida magna, vitae rutrum nibh viverra id. Duis eu nibh dolor. Pellentesque congue a dui in volutpat. Ut non placerat
      massa. Donec sollicitudin risus hendrerit tortor dignissim pharetra. Nam eu erat vel nulla elementum dictum consequat ut mauris. Donec egestas in nunc ut convallis. Fusce elit nisl, pulvinar et varius sed, sodales non elit. Duis a augue non quam
      maximus volutpat. Proin rhoncus lacus tempor, laoreet massa nec, venenatis tellus. Suspendisse eros sem, convallis vel risus ac, ultrices mattis justo. Morbi sit amet lectus vestibulum, lobortis tortor sed, tempor mi. Aliquam pretium, risus egestas
      sodales lobortis, sem sem vulputate elit, in lacinia neque tellus non elit.</p>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at nibh malesuada, imperdiet purus et, laoreet diam. Vivamus ullamcorper gravida magna, vitae rutrum nibh viverra id. Duis eu nibh dolor. Pellentesque congue a dui in volutpat. Ut non placerat
      massa. Donec sollicitudin risus hendrerit tortor dignissim pharetra. Nam eu erat vel nulla elementum dictum consequat ut mauris. Donec egestas in nunc ut convallis. Fusce elit nisl, pulvinar et varius sed, sodales non elit. Duis a augue non quam
      maximus volutpat.</p>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at nibh malesuada, imperdiet purus et, laoreet diam. Vivamus ullamcorper gravida magna, vitae rutrum nibh viverra id. Duis eu nibh dolor. Pellentesque congue a dui in volutpat. Ut non placerat
      massa. Donec sollicitudin risus hendrerit tortor dignissim pharetra. Nam eu erat vel nulla elementum dictum consequat ut mauris. Donec egestas in nunc ut convallis. Fusce elit nisl, pulvinar et varius sed, sodales non elit. Duis a augue non quam
      maximus volutpat. Proin rhoncus lacus tempor, laoreet massa nec, venenatis tellus. Suspendisse eros sem, convallis vel risus ac, ultrices mattis justo. Morbi sit amet lectus vestibulum, lobortis tortor sed, tempor mi. Aliquam pretium, risus egestas
      sodales lobortis, sem sem vulputate elit, in lacinia neque tellus non elit.Fusce elit nisl, pulvinar et varius sed, sodales non elit. Duis a augue non quam maximus volutpat. Proin rhoncus lacus tempor, laoreet massa nec, venenatis tellus. Suspendisse
      eros sem, convallis vel risus ac, ultrices mattis justo. Morbi sit amet lectus vestibulum, lobortis tortor sed, tempor mi. Aliquam pretium, risus egestas sodales lobortis, sem sem vulputate elit, in lacinia neque tellus non elit.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```